# using string.split in entity to traverse tree depth

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, tree

i have the following self-referencing table

```
public partial class products_category
    {
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string category_name { get; set; }
    public string category_description { get; set; }
    //self referencing to table id
    public Nullable<long> Parent_Id { get; set; }
    public string navPath {get; set; }
}
```

here string navpath contains all the leading parents for a child categroy, say:

```
"Clothes" = 1 Parent_id=null, navpath=""
"Silk" = 2 Parent_id=1 navpath="1"
"Silk Suit"=3 parent_id=2 navpath="1-2"
"Saree" =4 parent_id=3 navpath="1-2-3"
"Dress Material"=5 parent_id=1 navpath="1" and so on....
```

now as per this scenario i want to access the flattend tree for frther processing for a certain depth only say to level 2 or until level 4 depth of children associated with navpath.

my idea regarding this issue was to approach using linq to ef this way:

```
var catTrees = db.products_category.Where(pc => pc.navpath.Split('-').Length < 4).ToList();
```

i am using the following link to do further traversing and tree generation:
https://bitlush.com/blog/recursive-hierarchical-joins-in-c-sharp-and-linq

and it is doing a great work so far, the only issue is i dont want to pre select whole table for processing. i want to achieve paging and a certain level of depth for first iteration, so i can maintain performance in case of thousand of records. [think of this as a category hierarchy or blog/youtube comments hierarchy].

but using the above ef linq command is giving the following error:

```
The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayLength' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

i checked with ef docs and other places in SO to know that string.split doesn't work with EF implicitly. but can we apply it using extension methods or can this tree selection have alternate approach without using string.split and hitting DB only ones?
please advice.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an issues with building SQL code out of your LINQ mpre specifically SQL which takes a string splits it on dash and counts the elements.

if you dont hate the idea of loading into memory then you can force anything :)

```
var catTrees = db.products_category.ToList().Where(pc => pc.navpath.Split('-').Length < 4).ToList();
```

The trick here is to force the execution of the SQL by adding the `.ToList()` when we want the data from the database. This is called realizing the data.

Even with that realization trick the count is faster

```
var catTrees = db.products_category.ToList().Where(pc => pc.navpath.Count(a => a == '-') < 3).ToList();
```

these solutions are essentially the same as

```
List<Result> filter() {
    List<Result> r = new List<Result>();
    foreach(var a in db.products_category) {
        if(a.navpath.Count(a => a == '-') < 3) {
            r.add(a);
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

When thinking about it the filter method is somewhat less memory intensive as it reads one and one and never stores everything in memory. (in theory at least, only a few really knows what the .NET compiler does in the shadows)

Comment: checking your suggestion

Comment: no luck DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.

Comment: ok, was worth a shot,. but here is a solution which always works.

Comment: but wont this load everything in memory killing the purpose of 'performance' in case of 100's of records?

Comment: It most deffinately will load everything into memory, but that opens up for the posibility of running non SQL compliant code on it. Anyways a few hundred lines are not much. a character is 32bit meaning 1 megabyte of data is ~33 thousand characters.

Comment: i have 1+' your answer, i  will accept it if no better solution come by other users

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you against using the `navpath` for checking depth.

If you can change your model, you could add an additional numeric `Depth` field for each category and populate it according its `navpath`, then you could select them from your code in this way:

```
var catTrees = db.products_category.Where(pc => pc.Depth < 3).ToList();
```

There are many ways to populate that new column, but the bottom line is that you will have to do it just once (given that you keep track of it every time you modify the `navpath` of a category).

One possible way of populating it would be looping through all categories, something like:

```
var allCategories =  db.products_category.ToList();
foreach(var category in allCategories)
{
  var depth = category.navpath == "" ? 0 : category.navpath.Split('-').Length + 1;
  category.Depth = depth;
}
allCategories.SubmitChanges();
```